# Scalaz ValidationNel: traverse is not a member of List

Tags: scala, validation, scalaz

Playing with Scalaz `ValidationNel`, I am trying to transform a `List[ValidationNel[String, MyType]]` to `ValidationNel[String, List[MyType]]`

My code:

```
import scalaz._
import scalaz.syntax.traverse._
import scalaz.std.list._
import Scalaz._

val ns: NodeSeq = // ...
val v: ValidationNel[String, List[MyType]] = 
  ns.toList.traverse[({ type l[X] = ValidationNel[String, X] })#l, MyType](extractMyType(_))

private def extractMyType(n: Node): ValidationNel[String, MyType] = //...
```

When compiling with sbt, I get:

> [error] MyClass.scala:xx: value traverse is not a member of List[scala.xml.Node]
>
> [error]             val v: ValidationNel[String, List[MyType]] = ns.toList.traverse[({ type l[X] = ValidationNel[String, X] })#l, MyType](extractMyType(_))

I could not get `traverseU` to work either but I would like this version to work before going further.

I am using scala 2.10.0 and scalaz 7.1.1

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Your imports are redundant but this should work. Can you reproduce with `import scalaz._, Scalaz._` and no custom types or `scala.xml` imports?

Comment: I was trying several imports. I made the change and I now get an other error for something probably different. How could this change correct this specific error though?

Comment: I posted a new question and I am sure you can help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394928

Comment: If I solve my overall problem and if this specific one is solved by your comment, I would happily accept it as an answer.